# SQL Server 2016 : Error running DTS package using dtexec from cmd line to export from table to flat file

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016, dtexec, export-to-text

I have the following software:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2016
- Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
- SQL Server Management Studio v18.2 (SSMS)

Running services:

```
C:\workspace> net start | grep -i sql
SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server CEIP service (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server Integration Services 13.0
SQL Server Integration Services CEIP service 13.0
SQL Server Launchpad (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server PolyBase Data Movement (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server PolyBase Engine (MSSQLSERVER)
SQL Server VSS Writer
```

I am using SSMS to create SSIS package to export data using SQL to a flat file

I run the package immediately and save the package to file system.

The data exported successfuly to the flat file.

But, when i try to run the package using bash script,

```
PATH="/cygdrive/d/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/DTS/Binn":"$PATH"
dtexec /F unload.dtsx
```

or

```
PATH="/cygdrive/d/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/130/DTS/Binn":"$PATH"
dtexec /F unload.dtsx
```

I get the following errors:

> Started:  7:46:55 PM
>   Error: 2019-08-30 19:46:56.07
>
> Code: 0xC0048020
>
> Source: Data Flow Task 1 Data Flow Task 1 (SSIS.Pipeline)
>
> Description: The version of Destination - demo_dat is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
>
> End Error
>
> Error: 2019-08-30 19:46:56.58
>
> Code: 0xC0048020
>
> Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline
>
> Description: The version of Destination - demo_dat, clsid {44152846-E5A6-4EDB-8B8E-7072209A7662} is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow.
>
> End Error
>
> Error: 2019-08-30 19:46:56.60
>
> Code: 0xC0048021
>
> Source: Data Flow Task 1 Destination - demo_dat [2]
>
> Description: The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "Flat File Destination;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;1".
>
> End Error
>
> Error: 2019-08-30 19:46:56.60
>
> Code: 0xC0047017
>
> Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline
>
> Description: Destination - demo_dat failed validation and returned error code 0xC0048021.
>
> End Error
>
> Error: 2019-08-30 19:46:56.60
>
> Code: 0xC004700C
>
> Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline

Comment: Did you ever figure this issue out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2016 in project properties that should help resolve the issue. Also, make sure that SQL Server integration services set up and running.

[visual studio project properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDcHX.png)

Comment: Do you ask for help with something you need to do? Or do you report on something you needed to do and mean that to answer the question? Please [edit] to clarify.